# In hyperbolic geometry, is the area of a circle approximately EQUAL to the circumference?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I know that the circumference of a circle of radius $R$ in hyperbolic geometry is $2π sinh R$. I believe this is approximately equal to $πe^R$.

I know that the area of a circle of radius $R$ in hyperbolic geometry is $2π(cosh R − 1)$. But this also appears to be approximately equal to $πe^R$.

I plotted all three of these functions on Wolframalpha, and the graphs do appear to be relatively identical when the range on the x-axis is large.

Have I made some mistake here? How can the circumference be equal to the area?

Comment: Obviously both $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ are close to $e^x$ if $x$ is positive and large. Is it really surprising? I guess in hyperbolic geometry we just have a isoperimetric inequality with a different constant.

Comment: A quick reference: https://books.google.it/books?id=mjb0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=isoperimetric+inequality+hyperbolic+geometry&source=bl&ots=4jcGOdyhmx&sig=tBjn-J3JQUP0Poo4uQTpNZNr1oo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzpP24mLHRAhVDxRQKHfR1AF8Q6AEIYzAH#v=onepage&q=isoperimetric%20inequality%20hyperbolic%20geometry&f=false

Comment: The way I like to think of this is that the area increases so quickly with radius that "most of" the area is very close to the circumference.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't equal, but as you've noticed they're approximately equal.

What's likely happening is that you've discovered that:
$$\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2},\qquad \cosh(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$

So, we have that:
$$2\pi\sinh R = \pi e^R-\pi e^{-R}$$
For large $R$ we get that $e^{-R}$ gets small, so we will get that $2\pi\sinh R\approx \pi e^R$.

Now, we have that:
$$2\pi(\cosh R-1) = \pi e^R+\pi e^{-R}-2\pi$$
There's no reason that this should be approximately equal to $\pi e^R$, unless you're choosing $R$ large enough that $\pi(e^{-R}-2\pi)$ is negligable compared to $\pi e^R$.  In this case, we would again have that it's approximately $\pi e^R$.

In both cases, they're aren't exactly equal.  They can be equal to good approximation for large $R$ though.